# Should the model or controller load data in Ember JS?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm struggling to find a definitive pattern for where to handle loading data for my models. To start, I should say that I'm using a simple `$.ajax` wrapper to load my data rather than Ember Data.

Looking at [this blog post from one of the Discourse developers](http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html), you can see he recommends implementing a static method on the Model with `reOpenClass` that will load the relevant data.

```
App.RedditLink.reopenClass({

  findAll: function(subreddit) {
    return $.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/" + subreddit + "/.json?jsonp=?").then(
      function(response) {
        var links = [];
        response.data.children.forEach(function (child) {
          links.push(App.RedditLink.create(child.data));
        });
        return links;
      }
    );
  }

});
```

On the other hand, [I found another blog post about handling data in Ember](http://jzajpt.github.io/2012/01/24/emberjs-app-architecture-data.html). This time it is recommended to put a wrapper around `$.ajax` and make the calls from the Controller.

```
App.booksController = Em.Object.create({
  content: null,
  populate: function() {
    var controller = this;
    App.dataSource.fetchBooks(function(data) {
      controller.set('content', data);
    });
  }
});
```

Is this a matter of preference or is there a convention in MVC I should be following here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with the first approach. The second blog post you mention is from January 2012, which in the Ember world is an eternity and is not the correct way of creating controllers anymore. You shouldn't need to create them from scratch (using Em.Object.create()) anymore. Nowadays Ember.js does this for you when you initialize the application. If I were you, I would also try to better understand the role of models, routes and controllers when loading/managing data. Start with the emberjs.com guides for that.

In any case, try to get away from blog posts from 2012, they're mostly outdated. You can also check out http://emberwatch.com for posts, they are doing a great job at keeping up to date with emberjs information.